# How to get current device language if it's been changed after app start?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, localization

When you start the app there are a lot of ways to get current device language:

- `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`
- `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`
- `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`
- `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`
- `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`
- `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

But if I change device language while app is running, none of those values will be updated.

Is there a universal way to get current device language, or do I need to write code for each platform independently?

- Android: `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Locale.Default.ToString().Replace('_', '-'))`
- iOS: `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier.Replace('_', '-'));`
- UWP: `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0].ToString())`

Comment: " if I change device language while app is running," - you change it in device's settings?  But app doesn't see the change? Sounds like a bug (or perhaps limitation) of Xamarin.Essentials. Worth creating a [github issue](https://github.com/xamarin/essentials/issues) for it. Unless someone is able to give you an answer here at SO.

Comment: When I set `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, I don't expect device's language to change. Same thing in reverse. When app starts `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is set to device's culture as a default value, after that it's decoupled from it. It represents culture of the app, not the device.
Do you mean that this API should be added? I agree and created a PR in XCT: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/pull/1200

Comment: I was confusing Device info with app state; your PR makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Each platform should provide a notification whenever the user changes the device's location or language. For example, iOS sends out a [`NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscurrentlocaledidchangenotification) (Objective-C version) or [currentLocaleDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1418141-currentlocaledidchangenotificati) (Swift version) that includes a language property.

You'll need to register for and observe the platform notifications using [Xamarin.Forms local notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications) procedure, which notes (bolding and italics added):

> Each platform handles the creation, display, and consumption of local notifications differently. This article explains how to **create a *cross-platform* abstraction to send, schedule, and receive local notifications** with Xamarin.Forms.

- [Create a cross-platform interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications#create-a-cross-platform-interface)
- [Consume the interface in Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications#consume-the-interface-in-xamarinforms)
- [Create and handle an Android interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications#create-the-android-interface-implementation)
- [Create and handle an iOS interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications#create-the-ios-interface-implementation)

There are a number of tutorials on how to do this. Search on *xamarin forms local notification consume tutorial* to find some. Note the term *local*. You're not wanting *push* notifications - that's something else.

**To perform this task more simply, you might be able to use a plugin**, such as [edsnider/localnotificationsplugin on GitHub](https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin). You might find more by replacing the terms *consume tutorial* with *plugin* in your search.

*Clarification*:

- **local** notifications occur intra-device, ie, the device or apps send notifications internally to be consumed by apps on the device.
- **push** notifications occur when a request is made to an external service, such as Azure. *That* service would then broadcast a corresponding notification to the appropriate device(s).

Comment: Local notifications **are** push notifications =) Yeah, I can write code for each individual platform, I was just wondering, whether Xamarin already provides cross-platform API for this.
There are issue with writing this API yourself. Like converting platform-spesific language representation to `CultureInfo`. Each platform has slightly different string language representation and not all cultures are supported by `CultureInfo`.

Comment: Local notifications **are not** push notifications =) Per [Xamarin's Getting Started with the iOS 10 Notification Framework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-with-the-ios-10-notification-framework/) (not just for iOS), *Local notifications are notifications that come from the device rather than from a notification service...*  As [Push Notifications in Xamarin Forms](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/push-notifications/) notes for a push (or *remote*) notification: *You would send a message to their infrastructure, in a specific format and they send it out to mobile devices.*

Comment: Also, dated 2/12/2021 (12 Feb 2021), sample code at: [Xamarin.Forms - Local notifications demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/local-notifications/)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant that as I understand, local notifications notify user about staff (produce a sound, appear on the screen, etc.), not the app. Language change should be an internal app event (maybe using `MessagingCenter`, or a custom `event`), and that event shouldn't be broadcasted to the user. Or can local notifications be used like `MessagingCenter`?

Comment: `MessagingCenter` does work similarly, though there's a difference in the pattern used (*publisher-subscriber* for `MessagingCenter` vs *observer* for local notifications). Both techniques allow your app to decide whether to let the user know something or simply handle the event in the background. (Those user notifications are usually called *alerts* - vocabulary - sheesh!) Check the links I provided, especially the demo link above, to see how the sample code works for local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```java
Java.Util.Locale currentLanguage = this.Resources.Configuration.Locales.Get (0);
```

I am using this call in Xamarin Android and it works fine for me. "this" is in class Android.App.Activity.