# change system configuration and settings from app in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, locale, maui

I want to change the system language programmatically.

So there is apparantly an app that can make scheduled changes for things like bluetooth on/off: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cz1cgl5cb0s&ab_channel=GadgetHacks

I found also a post on how do that for Bluetooth for Android: [How to activate/deactivate bluetooth in .Net MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76858093/how-to-activate-deactivate-bluetooth-in-net-maui)

I found also a few ways on how to retrieve the language: [How to get current device language if it's been changed after app start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67096288/how-to-get-current-device-language-if-its-been-changed-after-app-start)

But I am looking for a way to change the language setting of the mobile phone, at least for Android but preferably it would be nice to know the api to change it for iOS as well. So something like this would be nice:

```
System.SetLanguage("en-us")
```

The end goal would be a simple functionality that allows to trigger scheduled language changes similar to the "timed toggles" app from the youtube video.

Comment: Do you want to set the phone's language or just app's language?

Comment: For iOS, you may refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61462264/20118901).

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT the phone's language

Comment: It's not recommended though. You may refer to [Android - change device system locale programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355330/android-change-device-system-locale-programmatically)